# Dart extension: don't access members with 'this' unless avoiding shadowing

Tags: dart, this, warnings, extension-methods

I'm learning to use the new Dart extension methods.

I'm doing this:

```
extension StringInsersion on StringBuffer {

  void insertCharCodeAtStart(int codeUnit) {
    final end = this.toString();
    this.clear();
    this.writeCharCode(codeUnit);
    this.write(end);
  }

  int codeUnitAt(int index) {
    return this.toString().codeUnitAt(index);
  }
}
```

So that I can do something like this:

```
myStringBuffer.insertCharCodeAtStart(0x0020);
int value = myStringBuffer.codeUnitAt(2);
```

However, I get the following lint warning:

> Don't access members with `this` unless avoiding shadowing.

Should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The warning you received means the following:
There is no need to reference the current instance using keyword `this`. Everything will work without reference to the current instance because the static extension method itself acts as an instance method of extensible type.

Simply put, just remove the reference to the current instance from your code.

From this:

```
final end = this.toString();
```

To this:

```
final end = toString();
```

Comment: I prefer to see `this` when writing extension methods.  I understand why the linter does this but I wish there was an exception to ignore within extension methods.  Seems like something is missing if you don't use it in that case.

Comment: @jaredbaszler This option is turned on in the package https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic
https://github.com/google/pedantic/blob/master/lib/analysis_options.1.9.0.yaml#L50
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_this.html.
It cannot be disabled globally, but you can disable it locally.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I just turn it off for my extension methods file and that works good enough.  Just a personal preference.

Comment: @jaredbaszler Yes. Separately for each file. Not for the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

It's a style thing, based on Dart's guide. There are examples in https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_this.html.
You can find more about style in https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style.

Answer (score 1):

I turn off this rule globally by changing "analysis_options.yaml"

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    unnecessary_this: false
```